# permission denied when running a shell script from crontab

Tags: unix

The script runs fine when I run it manually but when I schedule in crontab, I get this error in mail

```
  /bin/sh: /usr/app/TomcatDomain/Requea_ACCDomain01/cpuusage.sh: Permission denied
```

Steps involved:

```
  crontab -e
```

in insert mode, added

```
  */6 * * * * /usr/app/TomcatDomain/Requea_ACCDomain01/ ./cpuusage.sh
```

Comment: Show `whoami`, `ls -l cpuusage.sh` and `cat cpuusage.sh`.

Comment: hi,i have changed the permission and it actually worked..just one confusion

Comment: i have added following line "*/10 * * * * /usr/app/TomcatDomain/Requea_ACCDomain01/cpuusage.sh /home/u5437353/logs/cpuusage.log 2>&1" in crontab

Comment: according to me it should create a file cpuusage.log in the path mentioned to print the echo statememt and also in case of error

Comment: but i can see it does not create a log file rather if i go the path ,i see a mail notification and in /var/spool/mail/root..i can  see the echo statement

Comment: Just add `>` to `*/10 * * * * /usr/app/TomcatDomain/Requea_ACCDomain01/cpuusage.sh > /home/u5437353/logs/cpuusage.log 2>&1`

Comment: thenks..it worked..yes i forgot to give the output redirection